# How to refresh screen in componentdidmount ( react native )?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I am use bottom navigation, i get value form asyncStorage  in componentDidMount but every time i have to hard refresh for new value, when i please first screen to second screen and get new value in first screen but new value is not updated. so how refresh first screen with new value

Answer (score 2):

In bottom navigation the component does not go out of scope. In other words, component does not reload so componentDidMount() won't be called again. Better to use state management like Redux or Mobx. Let them handle the changes instead of reading from asyncStorage. If a Mobx Store gets updated it'll automatically refresh your values wherever you are accessing it.

Comment: how to transfer value one screen to another screen in bottom navigation

Answer (score 1):

ComponentDidMount is executed only at the start. So if you want to update data again and again after a specified time you might have to use something like setInterval in componentDidMount or if you want to fetch new data whenever a user clicks on something then you can do that by making a new separate function which would fetch data and update the state.
Whenever you update the state, the component almost instantly rerender.

Answer (score 0):

### Try Setting unmountOnBlur to true in navigation options

So every time the screen goes out of focus it is unmounted and when you come back to screen it is mounted again and data will be refreshed

[Using unmountOnBlur - Bottom Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur)